# Polymelic hexapods – how and why?

Tags: evolution, dragons, mutation, cryptids

In a seed world not too far away, a small mammal will have a bodily change that will one day give the draconic rank to its descendants, Of course if that is possible.
polymelia is a birth defect in which an affected individual has more than the usual number of limbs. It is a type of dysmelia. In humans and most land-dwelling vertebrates, this means having five or more limbs. The extra limb is most commonly shrunken and/or deformed.However, in the case of the draco mammal, this polymelia (more specifically notomelia) is functional,When you read this you might think that this isn't a question,but I'm just here to ask
**How could this notomelia be functional? Are there cases of functional polymely? why would they keep this and how would they pass it on? and there is a specific environment that at least that wouldn't be a disadvantage **

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions at once. Please remember that there's a requirement that every post asks a single focused question. Open ended questions, or questions asking us to generate ideas of brainstorm for you are not permitted on this site.